# Blender Render is transparent and not showing anything

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency

[image]

All my meshes have the render and view check on.
I tried using different cameras(having them as the main camera for rendering).
My composite also has the input going into the output.
I haven't touched anything on cameras or render settings, it happened randomly.
The problem is the same for both eevee and cycles.
It's also not showing up on the viewer for the composite.

[image]

This is what it should show

[image]

I've been searching for this for hours and couldn't find the solution, sorry if it's a duplicate.

[image]

Comment: Could you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've uploaded a video in the *Video Sequencer*. As the *Output > Post Processing > Sequencer* option is enabled by default, it will try to render this video strip. Remove the video strip or disable this option.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a legend.